# Creating new objects by dynamically enumerating keys of others

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-in-loop

I have an array of objects with named keys as follows:

```
Array [
        {
          'postal1': 111, // number
          'postal2': 222, // number
          'town': 'London', // string
        },
        {},{},... // Objects with same properties
      ]
```

The array is created after DOM and populated dynamically from a backend, so from the very beginning it's just an empty array.

Having all this I want to create a new object where *keys* will be `town` and their *values* will be an array of two other keys `postal1` and `postal2`.

```
Object {
  'London': [111,222],
  'town...': [rand,rand],
}
```

How one could make it in the most efficient way?

Comment: Can a city appear in the array more than once?

Comment: Thank you for your question! Actually no, all keys will be unique. I've forgot to mention it. But what if it does? We have to somehow rename duplicates?

Comment: You can rename duplicates, override or combine them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Array.reduce()` to generate an object from the array:

```js
const data = [{
  'postal1': 111, // number
  'postal2': 222, // number
  'town': 'London', // string
}];

const result = data
  .reduce((r, { town, postal1, postal2 }) => {
    r[town] = [postal1, postal2];
    
    return r;
  }, {});
  
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Could you please tell if .reduce() is faster than .map()? Any pitfalls?

Comment: `Array.map()` generates an array from another array. In this case `.forEach()` should be used. Anyway, there should be any difference in performance between the two.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var A= [
    {
      'postal1': 1110, // number
      'postal2': 2220, // number
      'town': 'A', // string
    },
    {
      'postal1': 1111, // number
      'postal2': 2221, // number
      'town': 'B', // string
    },
   {
      'postal1': 1112, // number
      'postal2': 2222, // number
      'town': 'C', // string
    }
  ];

  var desiredResult={};
  A.forEach(function(a){
     desiredResult[a.town]=[a.postal1, a.postal2];
  });

  console.log(desiredResult);
```

---

**But** this is faster than `all`:

```
var i=0,
    result={}; 
for(; i<A.length; i++) result[A[i].town]=[A[i].postal1, A[i].postal2];
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and fiddle! Could you please tell if .map() is more efficient than .reduce()? Any pitfalls here?